# Elementary periodic point is a finite set in a compact manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $f: M \to M$ to be a diffeomorphism where $M$ is a  finite dimensional compact manifold. We say that a fixed point $p$ (i.e., $f(p)=p$) is elementary if $1 \notin sp(Df_{p})$. *Suppose that every fixed point of $M$ is a elementary fixed point.*

**Claim:** There exists only a finite number of elementary fixed points.

I tried to show that the elementary points is discret set, but I am stuck in this.

The statement is from Robinson's Dynamical systems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us deal with the problem locally. Let $p\in M$ be an elementary fixed point. Using charts, you can assume that $p=0$ and that $f(0)=0$. If $1\notin\operatorname{Sp}(Df_0)$, then $D(f-\operatorname{Id})_0$ is invertible. So, by the inverse function theorem, $f-\operatorname{Id}$ is injective in some neighborhood $U$ of $0$. But then, since $(f-\operatorname{Id})(0)=0$, if $q\in U\setminus\{0\}$, then $(f-\operatorname{Id})(q)\neq q$. In other words, $f(q)\neq q$. So, near $0$ there aro no other fixed points. Reverting to the original situation, you deduce that near $p$ there are no other fixed points.

Therefore, the elementary fixed points form a discrete set.

Comment: Can you clarify one point please? I understand that infinite number of fixed points on a compact manifold inevitably means that all accumulation points of a set of fixed points are also fixed points. Thus there is a sequence of elementary fixed point that converges to a not necessarily elementary fixed point. The similar line of reasoning (which relies on the fact that elementary fixed point has no other fixed points near it) works if we put assumption that all fixed points are elementary beforehand. But I don't understand how the contradiction could be obtained now.

Comment: ok, you are right,  we assume that every fixed point is an elementary fixed point.

Comment: @Evgeny Actually, what I proved was that the elementary fixed points form a discrete set, because the OP wrote that he “tried to show that the elementary points is discret set”. Only later did he add to the question the assumption that all fixed points are elementary. Using this assumption, together with the compactness of the whole space, it follows that there can be only finitely many elemetary fixed points.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much for clarification! The set of fixed points in your proof is discrete in a sense of topology induced by topology, right?

Comment: @Evgeny That's it.